# How to do a y/n option in a do while loop?

Tags: java

I'm wondering if anyone could steer me in the right direction, im just beginning java and i am having trouble with string validation, what i want to do here is repeat the loop for each child, repeat the loop for as many books as you want for each child and then for it to exit when there are no children left. Im struggling with the y/n option and how to make it so that only those two options are valid otherwise the user would be shown invalid option try again. Any help would be greatly appreciated!Really stumped here!

```
     int childcounter=1;
    do{
      System.out.print("What is your childs first name "+childcounter+" of " +nochild+"?");
      cfn=k.next();
      System.out.print("What is "+cfn+"'s age?");
      cage=k.nextInt();
      System.out.println();
      do {
      System.out.print("What is the title of the book that " +cfn+ "would like?");
      btitle=k.next();      
      System.out.print("Price of '"+btitle+"' ?");
      costbook=k.nextDouble();  
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("Do you want to finish? y/n ");
      finished=k.next();
    }
    while(finished.equals("N") || (finished.equals("n")));
      childcounter++;
    }
while (childcounter <= nochild); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
System.out.print("Do you want to finish? y/n ");
String finished = k.next();
```

add

```
while (!java.util.Arrays.asList("y","n","Y","N").contains(finished)) {
    System.out.println(" Invalid option. Try again.");
    System.out.print("Do you want to finish? y/n ");
    finished = k.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using equalsIgnoreCase('n') would reduce the amount of code you have to type.

Use this instead.

```
while (finished.equalsIgnoreCase('n')
{

//method body here in the style that @halfbit suggested.
childcounter++;
}
```